# How to stop do while read line shell script after certain time?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am executing this command:

```
tail -f rest.log | while read 
LOGLINE
do
    [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Finished building"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail
done
```

It will read a log file until string 'Finished building' appears in the file. If so, it will kill the `tail` command. Sometimes the string will never appear. For this case I want to quit the loop after a certain time. Kind of a timeout. Lets say it should stop searching the string after 5 minutes. How can I achieve this? I tried to use timeout in front of the first `tail` command, which did not work for me.

Comment: How did it *not* work? It works fine here: `timeout 3s tail -f /etc/hosts  | while read FOO; do   sleep 5s; done` results in `Terminated` 3 seconds later.

Comment: Yeah `timeout` command's working fine! `# timeout 1m tail -f rest.log | while read ; LOGLINE; do     [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Finished building"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail; done
Terminated` -- Its terminated after `1 minute`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `read` has built in timeout option `-t`!

```
while read -t 10 LOGLINE 
do
  [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Finished building"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail
 done
```

The above terminates after `10 seconds`. Mention your required timeout in `seconds`. For more refer `man read`

```
read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the timeout command having the while loop in another script:

```
timeout 300 script_that_searches_for_finished_build.sh
```

The script will run for 5 minutes and stop.